# Error running or compiling this code java...Very confused program wont run

Tags: java, terminal

This program wont run on netBeans or compile in terminal...I dont think i have any erros in the itself..
This program needs to display the area of a circle
there cannot be any invalid input (letters, &^#,..etc)

Please and thank you for your time ;)

```
 **import java.util.Scanner; 


    /**
     *
     * @author Omar Sugule
     */
    public class AreaCircle {


        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // read the keyboard
    try {
        double r = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input, please enter a number");
        //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that their input was weird.
    }

    System.out.println("This program will calculate the area of a circle");

    System.out.println("Enter radius:");//Print to screen

    double r = sc.nextDouble(); // Read in the double from the keyboard






    double area = (3.14 *r * r); 
    String output = "Radius: " + r + "\n";
    output = output + "Area: " + area + "\n";
    System.out.println("The area of the circle  is " + area);

        }
    }**
```

Comment: So you're not seeing any compilation errors at all? What happens when you run it? You should probably tell us more of the important details about your problem.

Comment: When you say that it "won't compile", do you mean that it gives you a compile error? If so -- don't you think it would be helpful to post that error?

Comment: seems you forgot to post the error message you are getting

Comment: If the '**' at the beginning and end of your code posting are actually in your file, then that's your answer.

Comment: works for me, except that it doesn't prompt for input until I enter a number, which is ignored, and then it prompts for the radius. then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You know that this won't work:

```
try {
    double r = sc.nextDouble();
}
catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
    System.err.println("Invalid Input, please enter a number");
    //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that their input was weird.
}
```

since you *declare* r from within the try block, it is only visible inside the try block and is completely invisible elsewhere (this is called being out of "scope").

Instead:

- Declare `double r` before the try block and initialize it to 0.0:
  `double r = 0.0; // corrected as per mfrankli`
- Try to get the input in the try block
- enclose all in a while loop and continue looping until the input is valid
- don't re-declare `r` after the try block.
- work on improving your code formatting, in particular to get your code indentation uniform. Doing this will make the code a *lot* easier for you and us to debug.
- Work on asking better questions here. It's usually a good idea to give all the information necessary to help you in the initial question. Yours leaves out a lot of stuff making us have to guess which can lead to incorrect or confusing answers.

Comment: I don't think you can assign null to a primitive double?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried out your program, and the only real problem that I see is that you have this bit at the beginning that waits for user input:

```
    try {
        double r = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input, please enter a number");
        //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that their input was weird.
    }
```

Since that code comes *before* the program produces any output, the effect is of a program that simply hangs; it's not obvious to the user that they should enter a number. (And indeed, they needn't bother worrying too much about the number they enter, since the program just prompts them to enter another number a bit later down:

```
    double r = sc.nextDouble(); // Read in the double from the keyboard
```

and it's this second one that is actually used.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asterisks at the beginning and end of file. The rest is okay, except having to press enter before actually giving any input.